# How do I fetch name from an object?

Tags: swift, eaaccessory

```
let temp   = printer.information?.reserved["accessory"];
print(temp)
```

Output:

```
Optional(Optional(<EAAccessory: 0x281d04db0> { 

  connected:YES 
  connectionID:40870953 
  name: TSP100 
  manufacturer: Star Micronics 
  modelNumber: TTRDFGIBI GY 
  serialNumber: 07657643f 
  ppid: (null) 
  regioncode: (null) 
  firmwareRevisionActive: 1.0.0 
  firmwareRevisionPending: (null) 
  hardwareRevision: 1.0.0 
  dockType:  
  certSerial: 15 bytes 
  certData: 908 bytes 
  protocols: (
    "jp.star-m.starpro"
) 
  delegate: (null) 

}))
```

The type of the above printed object is **Any**.

Not sure how to get the value of **name** from the above object.

Comment: Did you tried «temp?.name» ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/externalaccessory/eaaccessory/1613801-name Cast is as a `EAAcessory` first, it's twice Optional?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting an `EAAAccessory` object you can access the `name` property. Something like this:

```
if let accessory = printer.information?.reserved["accessory"] as? EAAAccessory {
   let name = accessory.name
   print(name)
} else {
   print("Unable to access accessory")
}
```